# Limit tomcat log files size and set rotation

Tags: tomcat

In my Tomcat server application i use simple System.out.println in order to print to log.
The log goes to a file called tomcat6-stdout.log

The size of this file is not limited which sometimes is of course a problem. How can i control the size of this file and how many "history files" are saved.

I tried adding the following to java options in tomcat6 properties but it did not help:

```
-Dlog4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=500KB
-Dlog4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use System.out as your logging framework as Tomcat simply redirects this to a file. Use a proper logging framework as that will then give you much more control over the output file(s). There is a wide choice of logging frameworks. It looks like you are already familiar with log4j so that seems like a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 0):

if your tomcat is in Linux, I suggest you to use logrotate.
logrotate is designed to ease administration of systems that generate large numbers of log files.
I used to rotate tomecat log by this, and here is the [steps](http://yumidea.com/Log_Rotation/).(refer to the paragraph "How to rotate logs through file size").